# Django template: how to show decimal value as currency format with dollar sign, thousand separator with zero or two decimal points

Tags: django, formatting

The field in models.py is:

```
order_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

if the *order_amount* value is **12345.67**, how to display it in Django template for the below two formats:

- without decimal point: **$12,346**
- with two decimal points:
  **$12,345.67**

Comment: Adding a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#how-to-create-custom-template-tags-and-filters) is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the built-in template filter floatformat (note: numbers are rounded not cut!)

```
${{value|floatformat:"2g"}}     987654321.987 -> 987,654,321.99
${{value|floatformat:"0g"}}     987654321.987 -> 987,654,322
```

see also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat

Comment: if the value is None, it will end with just showing the dollar sign, is there a way to include the dollar sign in formatting?

Comment: see django template tags {% if value != None %}${% endif %}

Comment: I know could use IF statement to deal with the dollar sign, but this is not so neat to do the formatting job with two parts, one for dollar sign the other part using floatformat, maybe better to use a custom filter?

Comment: yes or go for django-money which provides a model field.